# Resign from Ph.D. project in a schengen country and go to better schengen country after finding a position

Tags: phd

I am not satisfied with the situation I have in the country that I live and conduct phd project. It passed around a year and now I want to apply for another position and go from this country. Does anybody have any experience if in the interview of another position ask about why do you leave what can I say? Also, am I right to do that? I know they cant capture me but what should I do legally and morally. I want to resign if I find a position.

Answer (score 2):

If they ask you why you want to leave, then just say the truth. If they find it a convincing argument, then the new position is likely a better match than your current one. If they don't find it convincing, then the new position is in all likelihood just as bad or worse than your current one, so you wouldn't want to move there anyhow.

It is morally OK to leave a PhD position, just as it is morally OK to quit any other job. The legal part, depends on the national laws. For instance, you may need to give x days/weeks/months notification before you can leave. We don't know what country you are in, so there is little we can tell you there. If if we could, you probably don't want to take legal advise from random persons on the internet...

More importantly, the way you phrase your question you seem to come from outside the Schengen area, so you should consider what this means for your visa. The only advise we can give you here is to get professional legal advise. The internet is great, but for really important stuff, like not getting deported, you really really really do *not* want to rely on it.

Comment: Thank you sir. for visa no issues the countries that I applied told me that if you legally live in this schengen country (where I am in) then after approval of the position they just assign you rp and then I can easily go there (anyway if anyone has also experience I would appreciate to share). One of the issues is resident permit issue in this country that I want to live. My visa was expired already and they do not issue my rp card in any way so this also increases my problem.

Comment: Regarding the contract I read it there is not specific things written there. Just it is written if you are unsuccessful or resign the contract will be terminated and so on.  Some people told me you should pay back some but I think it is not correct. Any how I could for example not do my responsibilities and they should then quit me such that I should not pay back in that case.

Comment: Yes internet might not be good but if anybody has experience that would be really good to share